# The flow of getting a coupon code vale designed in <p> tag and stored in Storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Up to now I have a flow of using the Session Storage and I cant stored the data into Session Storage. 
When users received the coupon from front end with

```
<p id="coupons">No. XXXXX </p>
```

And I want to get the value XXXXX and stored into Session Storage so that when users wants to received another coupon code (which is generated randomly), they cant received because they already have the coupons stored in Session Storage with var check = 1. Details as below

```
var coupons = document.getElementById("coupons");
    sessionStorage.setItem("flat" , 0);

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" || typeof(Storage) !== 0){
        sessionStorage.setItem("flat", 1);
        sessionStorage.coupons = coupons.value;
        sessionStorage.setItem("coupon", sessionStorage.coupons);

    } else {
        console.log("Already received the coupon");
    }
```

When I checked on browser and it is just only flat = 1, I dont see the value XXXXX that I want to stored. And I cant check the flat = 1 when refresh the browser to get the "Already received the coupon". Is there anything wrong in this case, please help. Thank you

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.value` to get the text, you need to use `.innerText`

```js
    var coupons = document.getElementById("coupons");
    var val = coupons.value;
    console.log(val);  // val == undefined

    var val = coupons.innerText;
    console.log(val);  // val == test
```

```html
<div id="coupons">test</div>
```

Comment: I forgot the value, sorry my bad. Just need to validate 1 more stuff when refresh the page

Comment: It said cannot READ the null properties of innerText

Answer (score 0):

To check if your sessionStorage contains coupon or not, you need to READ value from it by

```
sessionStorage.getItem('flat');
```

to save value use

```
sessionStorage.setItem('flat', coupons.innerText )
```

Comment: If I dont say wrong, i need to update first. Please correct for me if I have some  misunderstanding information
First, I will get the value from <p> tag with var coupons = document.getElementById("coupons") (my id is coupons)

I create a flat key with variable is 0 default (0 means no coupon)

Then using sessionStorage to get the flat with you line of code
sessionStorage.getItem('flat') 

Then start with the if() else() statement. Is it correct

Comment: First you read coupon from html/api. Then you check sessionsStorage using `getItem` on key `flat` (you can choose arbitrary key name), then if value is empty, then you save value using `setItem`